# Coin Toss Experiment Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, combinations

consider an experiment of tossing a coin.heads appear about once out of every three tosses. if this experiment is repeated, what is the probability of the event that heads appear exactly twice during the first five tosses

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think? What previous knowledge do you have about probabilities?

Comment: For 5 coin tosses we would have 32 different outcomes. Out of these I need to consider only those outcomes which have a H in the first 3 tosses and another H in the next 2 coin tosses. Thus a total of 6 favourable cases. 6 out of 32 is the probability the question is asking for. This is how I have worked out. I don't know whether it's right or not

Comment: So, your question is a bit different from the one you actually asked in above. Having two heads in the first five tosses is different from having one in the first three tosses and another one in the next two tosses. Please edit your question if it is indeed the latter.

Comment: Consider that you are tossing a coin 5 times. The question says a head appears once out of every three tosses (no 3 consecutive Tails will appear ) This means that there must be 1 head in the first 3 tosses (out of the 5). Now the next head can appear in 4th or 5th or 6th toss. The question asks for exactly 2 heads in 5 tosses. So , the first head has occurred in one of the first 3 and now the next will be in either 4th or 5th. Hence a total of 6 possibilities of getting 2 heads in 5 tosses such that 1 in every 3 tosses is a  head

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the concept of probability. Saying that heads appears **about** once in every three tosses means that if you tossed that coin an infinite number of times, you would have twice as many tails as heads on average. That does not give you any absolute info about 3 consecutive tosses only.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a direct application of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):
$$
 P(X=k)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
In your case, $X$ would count the number of heads, $p=\frac{1}{3}$ is the probability of heads appearing, $n=5$ is the total number of tosses and $k=2$ is the number of heads that we would like to get.